# Handlebars helper for checking if string is not in a list of strings?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm looking for a Handlebars helper that will help me exclude based on whether the expression is equal to any string in a list of strings.

Something like

{{#if expression != [strings, to, be, excluded]}}

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to write a custom helper to do that.  See https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers

Comment: I think it would be more inline with the spirit of this site if you were to attempt such a helper yourself and then provide your solution here for others to help you fix it.

Comment: Possibly https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#inArray